# Making Rake::TestTask run "single-threaded"

Tags: ruby, rake, minitest

We have some tests in our MiniTest::Spec test suite that pass when each test directory is run individually, but fail when the entire suite is run.

Instead of spending hours trying to track down the reason for the failures, I thought it would be easier to just run each test directory in its own TestTask instance, like so:

```
Dir.new('spec').each do |f|
  next if f.start_with? '.'
  if File.directory? File.join('spec', f)
    Rake::TestTask.new('test') do |t|
      t.libs << "app" << "spec"
      t.test_files = FileList["spec/#{f}/*_spec.rb"]
      t.verbose = true
    end
  end
end
```

This causes the tests in each directory to run in "parallel", however. TestTask.new seems to execute each test in a separate thread (though I haven't figured out why yet).

Is there any way to avoid this behavior? I want each directory to run sequentially, since without this I'm running into "stack too deep" errors.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, TestTask.new, through a long and winding path, eventually calls Kernel.system, which causes each task to run in a subshell.

Comment: Thanks, @ColinR. I discovered that as well, but I thought Kernel.system waits until the subshell command completes so it can return a status. It's hard to tell from the TestTask source, but evidently each call to TestTask.new ends up spawning a new parallel process. I was hoping to find some way of avoiding this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get this solved? I need this functionality as well and wanted to check what approach did you use.

Comment: Sorry, @Chetan, not yet. We'll be sure to post back here if we do solve it!